# Oracle TTC error in MVC Entitiy Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I want to use the Model First workflow in Entity Framework with Oracle SQL.
I can create new elements into the db with the Create Controller, but when I want to display it I got a not so detailed TTC error message:

```
TTC Error
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: TTC Error

Source Error: 


Line 18:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             return View(db.VALLALAT.ToList());
Line 21:         }
Line 22: 

Source File: ...\Controllers\VallalatController.cs    Line: 20
```

I got this error with every model, that got a data in the SQL table

```
[Exception: TTC Error]
   OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean bAllInputBinds, Int32 arrayBindCount, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]& rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean& bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, List`1& implicitRSList, Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired) +3350
   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleDataReaderImpl.FetchMoreRows(Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Boolean fillReader, Boolean returnPSTypes) +1511
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Read() +1365
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +36

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.HandleReaderException(Exception e) +145
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +49
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +41
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +112
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +387
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
```

My enviroment:

- Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.2.0 - 64bi
- Entity Framework 6.0
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess & EntityFramework 18.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay! I got the answer.

The Visual Studio generated me the table, with an NCLOB property. I changed the NCLOB to VARCHAR2 and now finally display the list correctly.

**Update:**
Don't forget to degrade the ODP.NET driver to 12.2 from 18.3

Comment: Yes, a TTC error is very severe. It suggests that client and server network layers no longer speak the same protocol. This can happen when there is more than about 2 major database versions between client and server (not a precise rule, check support documents for exact compatibility version ranges)

Answer (score 0):

Degrade the ODP.NET driver to 12.2

Answer (score 0):

as Benzo said "change the NCLOB to VARCHAR2" and it worked for me
**but**
Don't  degrade the ODP.NET driver to 12.2 from 18.3 (if the ODT is 18.3)